# Xamarin Not able to view Android designer view

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to learn android using xamarin.I have installed xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 with update 3 and Android SDK.I have created a sample application as per the demo in pluralsight.

Iam not able to open designer view of .axml. I tried right Click View Designer option but it is opening xml code. 
I tried "open with"option after googling where they  said there will be android designer option.But I didn't find it.

I tried to write the code directly in .xaml like creating button but after that it is not creating Id class in resources.designer.cs.

How to create controls in .xaml without Designer? Or how to get the designer so that we can drag and drop controls in .axml?

Comment: `it is not creating Id class` you need to build it. Only after you build, it would create. And yes, designer view is quite buggy in Xamarin. You likely will have to do everything in XML manually.

Comment: So that means I can't open designer view? But in the demo he is doing everythign in designer by just drag and drop.Can't I do like that?

Comment: you should ask him ,not me. I only experienced bunch of bugs trying to use designer view in Xamarin.  It works good in Android Studio, but not in Visual Studio.

Comment: Okay.Thanks for the comment

Comment: By `it is not creating Id class in resources.designer.cs.`, sometime we will meet that, please delete bin/obj and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: I am not able to see even designer tab.Can someone tell how to get the designer tab open atleast to see the design